# Render password value using f:field in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I’m using f:field in order to render a custom Cmd object.

```
class CustomCmd implements Validateable {

    String user
    String password

    static constraints = {
        user blank: false, email: true
        password blank: false, password:true
    }

}
```

Then in my gsp page I use

```
<fieldset class="form">
  <f:with bean="${cmd}">
    <f:field property="user"/>
    <f:field property="password"/>
  </f:with>
</fieldset>
```

The password is not shown on the page (with the standard **** bullets): the field has no value, but the user field is filled with the right value.

There is a way to fill the password field using f:field tag?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the wanted behaviour:
https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/issues/60

I'm not agree with the developers... BTW this is not a bug